# Hibernate - Duplicate entry made while Updating @OneToMany Column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have userInfo Entity and ChannelDetails Entity

```
public class UserInfoDO implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "`type`")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "`value`")
    private String value;
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Date createdOn; 

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "identifierId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ChannelDetailsDO> channelDetails = new HashSet<ChannelDetailsDO>();
}

public class ChannelDetailsDO {

    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "channel")
    private String channel;
    @Column(name = "is_blocked")
    private int isBlocked;
    @Column(name = "blocking_reason")
    private String blockingReason;
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Date createdOn;
    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    private Date updatedOn;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = UserInfoDO.class, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "identifier_id")
    private UserInfoDO identifierId;
}
```

There is an Update Scenario, where for a UserInfo, the Channels can be updated, added

eg: for User with id=1 and value = 2222,
the channelDetails are [{channel: 123, isblocked : true , blockReason : "some"},{channel: 124, isblocked : true , blockReason : "some"}]

Now I want to Update the user with Channel details of 124 and Parallely want to add one more channelDetail 125. When I am doing this. Duplicate Rows are created for 124. to resolve this I have kept unique-constraint on channel column, but then 125 is not getting added with error:
null id in ChannelDetailsDO entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

What changes are required which can update the ChannelDetails as well Add them if not already in DB.

Comment: add the creation method and also is the Channel.id an auto-generated id column on the database level?

Comment: A wild guess! Just try implementing `equals` and `hashcode` method in your `ChannelDetailsDO` class if you haven't done it already.